# Subscripts in tick labels with a discrete variable mapped to x

Tags: r, ggplot2, subscript, ggtext

I was wondering how to put a subscript in my x-axis tick labels. Not in the axis label, as in most other posts, hence from the values already in the data frame.

Here is a reproducible code example, I would like the letters in brackets to be subscripts.

```
p_t<- c(rep("FW - P[H]",3),rep("FW - P[L]",3),rep("FW - F",3),rep("FW - SSWB",3),rep("C - F",3),rep("C - P[L]",3),rep("C - P[H]",3))
s_t<-rep(c("A","B","C"),7)
c_t <-c(0,1,2,+
              0,3,2,+
              0,4,3,+
              0,3,4,+
              0,6,5,+
              0,2,4,+
              0,7,2)
df_t1<-data.frame(p_t,s_t,c_t)

ggplot(data=df_t1,aes(y=c_t, x=p_t,fill = s_t))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           color="black")
```

Comment: A good question with several different possible answers. I have changed the question title to make it more descriptive, and in this way more useful to those searching in the future. I have also slightly edited the text of the question to match the terms used in documentation and books on 'ggplot2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach is to use the recently released package 'ggtext', but its use requires a change to the coding of the subscripts in the example data as 'ggtetxt' implements support for Markdown and HTML markup. In this first code chunk I changed the example data, but if the data are as in the question, `gsub()` can be used, as shown in the second code chunk, to replace the square brackets by the HTML coding for subscripts on-the-fly.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

p_t <- c(rep("FW-P<sub>H</sub>", 3), rep("FW-P<sub>L</sub>", 3), rep("FW-F", 3),
        rep("FW-SSWB", 3), rep("C-F", 3), rep("C-P<sub>L</sub>", 3),
        rep("C-P<sub>H</sub>", 3))
s_t <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 7)
c_t <- c(0, 1, 2, +0, 3, 2, +0, 4, 3, +0, 3, 4, +0, 6, 5, +0, 2, 4, +0, 7, 2)
df_t1 <- data.frame(p_t, s_t, c_t)

ggplot(data = df_t1, aes(y = c_t, x = p_t, fill = s_t)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color = "black") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]

String substitution can be done on-the-fly in `scale_x_discrete()` so that the conversion to HTML markup can also be automated if desired.

```r
p_t <- c(rep("FW - P[H]", 3), rep("FW - P[L]", 3), rep("FW - F", 3),
         rep("FW - SSWB", 3), rep("C - F", 3), rep("C - P[L]", 3),
         rep("C - P[H]", 3))
s_t <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 7)
c_t <- c(0, 1, 2, +0, 3, 2, +0, 4, 3, +0, 3, 4, +0, 6, 5, +0, 2, 4, +0, 7, 2)
df_t1 <- data.frame(p_t, s_t, c_t)

ggplot(data = df_t1, aes(y = c_t, x = p_t, fill = s_t)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) {gsub("\\[", "<sub>", gsub("\\]", "</sub>", x))}) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown())
```

Note: The tick labels are not exactly the same as when using R expressions as the characters are here retained unchanged and spacing around dashes is neither added nor modified. In this case dashes are visibly shorter.

Answer (score 0):

An approach based on 'ggplot2' is to set the tick labels to be R expressions. (The last code chunk in this answer is the best answer, while the other code chunks attempt to give more general answers and present alternatives.)

We can easily substitute character data values by R expressions using `scale_x_discrete()`. But as shown here, this is straightforward only if we use as data values strings that are valid R names. (The columns in the plot are displayed in alphabetical order according to the values stored in `p_t`, unless this order is altered using the `breaks` parameter to `scale_x_discrete`, consequently order is not the same for this example.)

```r
p_t <- c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3),
    rep("d", 3), rep("e", 3), rep("f", 3),
    rep("g", 3))
s_t <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 7)
c_t <- c(0, 1, 2, +0, 3, 2, +0, 4, 3, +0, 3, 4, +0, 6, 5, +0, 2, 4, +0, 7, 2)
df_t1 <- data.frame(p_t, s_t, c_t)

ggplot(data = df_t1, aes(y = c_t, x = p_t, fill = s_t)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(a = expression(FW - P[H]), 
                              b = expression(FW - P[L]), 
                              c = expression(FW - F),
                              d = expression(FW - SSWB), 
                              e = expression(C - F), 
                              f = expression(C - P[L]),
                              g = expression(C - P[H])))
```

The values in the data are translated using the named vector of expressions. The code above is not yet a full answer to the question, but it is easier to understand than the proper answer, which I show below, in two stages. The difference is that we need to use backticks to protect the names when creating the vector of labels, because the data values contain characters that need special handling when used in R nanes.

```r
p_t <- c(rep("FW - P[H]", 3), rep("FW - P[L]", 3), rep("FW - F", 3),
    rep("FW - SSWB", 3), rep("C - F", 3), rep("C - P[L]", 3),
    rep("C - P[H]", 3))
s_t <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 7)
c_t <- c(0, 1, 2, +0, 3, 2, +0, 4, 3, +0, 3, 4, +0, 6, 5, +0, 2, 4, +0, 7, 2)
df_t1 <- data.frame(p_t, s_t, c_t)

ggplot(data = df_t1, aes(y = c_t, x = p_t, fill = s_t)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(`FW - P[H]` = expression(FW - P[H]), 
                              `FW - P[L]` = expression(FW - P[L]), 
                              `FW - F` = expression(FW - F),
                              `FW - SSWB` = expression(FW - SSWB), 
                              `C - F` = expression(C - F), 
                              `C - P[L]` = expression(C - P[L]),
                              `C - P[H]` = expression(C - P[H])))
```

I show these simpler cases, as the question is very specific, and for most future readers one of the simpler answer is likely to be all what they need. This approach can be used to selectively replace individual tick labels instead of all of them as shown above.

[image]

We can also automate the construction of the vector passed as argument to `labels`.

```r
labels.vec <- parse(text = unique(df$p_t))
names(labels.vec) <- unique(df$p_t)

ggplot(data = df_t1, aes(y = c_t, x = p_t, fill = s_t)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(labels.vec))
```

This code only requires that the values in `df$p_t` can be parsed into R expressions. In other words, this solution is fully driven by the values stored in the data frame.

The simplest, and recommended approach, is to do the parsing on-the-fly. Because of parameter naming and positions in the definition  of `parse()` we cannot directly pass `parse` as argument to parameter `labels`, we need to define an anonymous function as wrapper.

```r
ggplot(data = df_t1, aes(y = c_t, x = p_t, fill = s_t)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) {parse(text = x)})
```

This final example is as simple or simpler than using 'ggtext', but does not allow adding color, etc. using embedded HTML tags, as is possible with 'ggtext'.

Note: The labels are not exactly the same as when using 'ggtext' as the "minus" character is here used for the dashes, and spacing around these dashes is adjusted for typesetting a math expression.